# Allow users to see only a selected set of data

Tags: articles, user-groups, permissions

I have a specific requirement and looking for a matching set of extensions.

I have a Joomla website where I allow users to login and see a selected article for each of them. That means, when the user logs in, he will see a menu item "My Page", but the user will be directed to an article which meant only to him. Other users should not see this article by any means.

**Use case:**

Let's imagine I have several suppliers registered on my website, where they don't know about others. This particular link will forward them to an article which shows the statistics of the products they supply. This doesn't need to be dynamic, so the admin will edit the article manually.

How can I achieve this?
(Sorry if this is not the right forum to ask such a specific question.)

Answer (score 0):

Create user groups and assign different data to be shown in which group.

[Joomla ACL](https://docs.joomla.org/Access_Control_List)